# Makeindex (imakeidx) distinguishes entries in main text and footnote

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I am compiling a text index of a large volume, with the help of `imakeidx` because I have two separate indexes. For some reason, entries in footnotes result in separate listing from entries in the main text. See the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{book}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\makeindex[name=texts,title=Texts,columns=3,options=-s mystyle -c -l] 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

3.28\index[texts]{Alphabet@\textbf{Alphabet}!3.28}\footnote{3.28\index[texts]{Alphabet@\textbf{Alphabet}!3.28}}

\printindex[texts]
\end{document}
```

The result is two entries of 3.28, which should have been combined into one, because the first entry has an unexplained space between `\textbf` and `{Alphabet}`. How can I avoid this:

```
  \begin{theindex}

  \item \textbf {Alphabet}
  \subitem 3.28, 1
  \item \textbf{Alphabet}
  \subitem 3.28, 1

  \end{theindex}
```

Comment: @egreg Oh I'll move my answer there then:-)

Comment: I've marked the question as duplicate; if the answers there are not clear or helpful for the problem at hand, please make us know. This is not a judgment of your question, just a way to keep the site as informative as possible, without spreading information across various questions/answers.

Comment: Did not realise that, thanks, answers very helpful.